# QLThumbnailImageCreate broken in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks, quicklook

I have code that makes a preview of 'any' file, it runs threaded in a Cocoa desktop app.

```
             CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, (CFStringRef) inFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
             if (url)
             {
                 cgImage = QLThumbnailImageCreate(nil, url, inSize, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options);
                 CFRelease(url);
             }
```

On 10.8 (and I think 10.9.0 and 1) I would get a real render - equivalent to pressing the space bar in the finder, but now I only get piddly icons or NULL.

In other words if you press spacebar in the Finder on 10.9 for a .m file, you see the files contents, but QLThumbnailImageCreate returns NULL.

Anyone else noticed this?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/message/25470656#25470656 is related com.apple.CFPasteboardClient

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that by deleting the app TextMate 2 (April 2014 version) (which I use) fixes this problem. TextMate has a bug in its Quicklook generator it seems.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/25470656#25470656

Is an example of someone running into the bug.